# Make each item the same size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've created a table from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68143597/14230069) code in my app. My problem is that when **the text in one cell requires more than one line, only the one cell will resize instead of all cells in the row**. This looks really ugly. I've already tried using `Modifier.onSizeChanged` to change the height of each other cell but it didn't work.

[image: Image of table]

Code:

```
data class Cell(
    val name: String,
    val weight: Float
)

@Composable
fun RowScope.TableCell(...) { /* same as in the linked code */ }

@Composable
fun MyTable(data: List<Something>) {
    val columns = listOf(
        Cell("a", .25f),
        Cell("b", .25f),
        Cell("c", .25f),
        Cell("d", .25f)
    )

    LazyColumn(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        item {
            Row {
                columns.forEach {
                    TableCell(
                        text = it.name,
                        weight = it.weight
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        items(data) {
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                TableCell(
                    text = it.somenumber.toString(),
                    weight = columns[0].weight
                )

                TableCell(
                    text = "Abc",
                    weight = columns[1].weight
                )

                TableCell(
                    text = it.somestring1,
                    weight = columns[2].weight
                )

                TableCell(
                    text = it.somestring2,
                    weight = columns[3].weight
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases, you should use `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`: it will override the height constraint which is set to infinity by scrollable `LazyColumn`. Then you can apply `Modifier.fillMaxHeight` to your `TableCell`.